# How to display key data of multiple objects on a render method?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have an array that contains multiple objects that each contains the following keys `item:"Hoodie" price:25 size:"large"` for example. I want to render this data but I cant figure out how to loop through the array and display the data for each object in a list. This is my component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {addCart} from './Shop';
import { removeCart } from '../../actions'; 
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

export class Cart extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {items: this.props.cart,cart: [],total: 0};
    }

    ...

    render() {
        return(
            <div className= "Webcart" id="Webcart">
                <div>
                    {this.state.items.map((item, index) => (
                        <li className='cartItems' key={index} />
                    ))}
                </div>
                <div>{this.countTotal()}</div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

...
```

How can I render the data (item name, price, and size) for each object in a list?

Comment: you can easily access your object properties inside your loop like so: `item.item,  item.price and item.size`

Comment: What you're doing will work just fine. Like Amr Aly said, you can use `item.name` etc to display the results. Like this: `<li className='cartItems' key={index}>{item.name}</li>`. Note: You might want to use something more unique than the index for the value of key. Maybe `item.name` if it's unique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on the right path, just add this code to your map:

```
{this.state.items.map((item, index) => {
    return <li className='cartItems' key={'cartItems_'+index}>
        <h4>{item.item}</h4>
        <p>Size: {item.size}</p>
        <p>Price: {item.price}</p>
    </li>
})}
```

Note the return and that the `<li />` is not a component but a "wrapper" or what you can call it. Also to keep it semantically you shouldn't wrap `<li>` elements inside a `<div>` but a `<ul>` but thats just a sidenote.

Comment: Well yes, but I don't know why you gave it the down vote because it just makes things clearer to use the regular return. I haven't misled him or anything, I just gave him my type of coding because others that haven't got the explicit knowledge of how returns work in ES6 might find it confusing if they don't spot out the `(` instead of `{`.

Comment: I downvoted because you said an explicit return was required. I removed the downvote now because you removed that part :)

Comment: Yes, when you pointed that out I looked over his code and saw the `(` and like I said, it is easy to miss..